# Is there a way to update secure URL's of apps created by our users?

Tags: ssl, facebook-graph-api

We are trying to beat the October 1 deadline. However, we need to update thousands of apps' Secure URL's for apps created by our users . In the past, we have used Admin.setAppProperties , but there is no way to update the Secure URL.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment to [a bug posted about this issue](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/142267955868571), [Facebook's Matthew Johnston wrote](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/142267955868571?fb_comment_id=fbc_10150293013081006_18494654_10150296401961006):

> We are actively working on this and will have this ready for you on Tuesday.

Comment: ^_^  They will likely not release the documentation for months, though.